# Change network location

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a Network Location shortcut that I created using the Map Network Drive / Add Network Location wizard. It is a custom location for an IP address of an external device. Unfortunately that device's IP can vary.

How can I quickly change the target IP of this shortcut (or whatever it is - it says "File folder") without deleting it and going through the wizard each and every time?

**EDIT:** I created a new shortcut using a non-IP URL, which resolved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this IP address is a Global Internet IP (*not* 192.168.x.x), then try using a dynamic dns server to change the numbers into letters (example.hostname.com). My recommendation is DynDns. It is popular and highly rated. Enter your remote drive's router settings and look for "Dynamic DNS", and there should be an option to enter your account credentials. This way, if the IP changes, the hostname doesn't. Enter the name you chose when setting up your account in the network drive wizard, and never have to change it again :).

If this IP address is a Local Network IP (192.168.x.x), then enter your router settings, and look for "DHCP Reservation", and create a reservation for your drive. Remember the IP you pick. Enter this IP into the Network Drive Wizard and never change it again :).

If you still want to know how to change a network drive's properties quickly, I have never found a way :/. Windows is very particular I guess. Sorry.

I hope this helped :D

Comment: Glad i could help :)